# Can I have more than one ellipsis in one function

Tags: r

```
skewness <- function(x, ...){
    if(!is.numeric(x))
        stop("x is not numeric")
    mean((x-mean(x,...)),...)/(var(x,...))^2
}
x <- rnorm(100)  
x[3] <- NA
skewness(x,na.rm=T)
[1] NA
```

I can not get the answer that I want. So how to use the ellipsis correctly. Especially when it comes to more than one ellipsis that I want to use.

Comment: See, for example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080972/using-multiple-ellipses-arguments-in-r) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r)

Comment: Check your definition of skewness.

Comment: See `e1071::skewness`. Rather than all the ellipses passing, one might also consider including and handing the  `na.rm` argument directly.

Comment: Yes but I just want to use it for an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one ellipsis and I think there are is one to many ().

```
skewness <- function(x, ...){
    if(!is.numeric(x))
        stop("x is not numeric")
    mean(x - mean(x, ...), ...) / (var(x, ...))^2
}
```

Comment: Right, in `mean((x-mean(x,...)))`, the first `x` may still have NAs.

Comment: Well, sometimes I will make those kinds of mistakes.