# How do you use tidydots(...) if a function you're writing also has optional parameters?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Is what I'm doing bad practice? I can't find anything specific to this topic, tidyeval docs don't mention it.

Writing a function that takes in a tibble, filtering parameters, grouping parameters and returns a summarized tibble.

```r
createTable <- function(counts, mapper = NULL,day = NULL, week = NULL, month = NULL, ...){

  # Check for optional param
  day_missing <- is.null(day)
  print(day_missing)
  month_missing <- is.null(month)
  week_missing <- is.null(week)
  mapper_missing <- is.null(mapper)

  # reassigns input params to new vars for use with dplyr::filter
  m <- month
  d <- day
  w <- week
  mp <- mapper

  # group, summarise, filter and score counts
  group_vars <- enquos(...)
  counts %>% # counts is always in the same format, which allows for the below filtering
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarise_at(summaryVars, sum) %>% # summaryVars is a global var, always the same variables being summed
    filter(if(month_missing) TRUE else month == m) %>% 
    filter(if(week_missing) TRUE else week == w) %>% 
    filter(if(day_missing) TRUE else day == d) %>%
    filter(if(mapper_missing) TRUE else mapper == mp) %>% 
    calcScores() # calcScores is a global function, it converts the summarised data above into scored data (e.g. count of 10 = scored as 250)

}
```

This does exactly what I need it to do, but only if all parameters are supplied implicitly

```r
test <- createTable(featureCounts2019, "mcglonee", NULL, NULL, 5, mapper, month, week)

#> Get expected output

test <- createTable(counts = featureCounts2019, mapper = "mcglonee", month = 5, mapper, month, week)

#> This won't work, R won't know what to do with the group_vars
```

I thought about supplying the group_vars as a list and then unlisting into enquos, but that throws me an error saying that objects in the list don't exist.

```r
createTable2 <- function(counts, mapper = NULL,day = NULL, week = NULL, month = NULL, group_vars){

  # Check for optional param
  day_missing <- is.null(day)
  month_missing <- is.null(month)
  week_missing <- is.null(week)
  mapper_missing <- is.null(mapper)

  # reassigns input params to new vars for use with dplyr::filter
  m <- month
  d <- day
  w <- week
  mp <- mapper

  group_vars <- unlist(group_vars)
  # group, summarise, filter and score counts
  group_vars <- enquos(group_vars)
  counts %>% # counts is always in the same format, which allows for the below filtering
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarise_at(summaryVars, sum) %>% # summaryVars is a global var, always the same variables being summed
    filter(if(month_missing) TRUE else month == m) %>% 
    filter(if(week_missing) TRUE else week == w) %>% 
    filter(if(day_missing) TRUE else day == d) %>%
    filter(if(mapper_missing) TRUE else mapper == mp) %>% 
    calcScores() # calcScores is a global function, it converts the summarised data above into scored data (e.g. count of 10 = scored as 250)

}

test2 <- createTable2(counts = featureCounts2019, mapper = "mcglonee", month = 5, group_vars = list(mapper, month, week))

#> Error in unlist(group_vars) : object 'mapper' not found
```

Not the end of the world since this funciton is just for me, but what if I am writing something as part of a package I think people will use, what then? How are you able to have both optional parameters and use tidydots?

Comment: I don't remember where I've read it but I recall as if it's something to do with R and not tidyeval per se. I think it's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080972/using-multiple-ellipses-arguments-in-r

Comment: @NelsonGon, thanks but I don't think that is quite the same issue. They want to associate different sets of parameters each with their own ```...```.  I want to be able to have optional arguments with ```...``` to catch parameters for ```group_by```  As it is right now my optional arguments are kind of pointless because you have to explicitly state that they're null or else you can't pass multiple params to the ```...```. This is becuase ```...``` acts on "list like objects' not list exactly, so you can't pass it a list of params

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a little convoluted, but I think the [Tidyverse design principles](https://design.tidyverse.org/dots-position.html) suggest a simple solution: place dots between your data argument and detail arguments like so:

```
   createTable <- function(counts, ..., mapper = NULL, 
                           day = NULL, week = NULL, month = NULL) { 

                   # function body
              }
```

As per design principles:

> this forces the user of your function to fully name the detail
> arguments, because arguments that come after ... are never matched by
> position or partially by name

Additionally, you can check explicitly for missing function arguments with `missing()`.